# My for loop doesn´t work well

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cell, nsindexpath

This is the loop for:

I would like that add 3 images (called `1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg`) to 3 rows that the table has. But with `>=` the view doesn´t appeared and with `==` only the first row has an image.

```
for (int i = 0; i >= indexPath.row; i++) {
        i++;
        NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        NSString *format = @".jpg";
        NSString *end= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", number, format];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:end];
    }
```

What I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are many thing wrong with you code, first lets start with the first line in your loop.

`i++` will increment the `i` which means you steps are 2 and not 1.

Second you are saying to keep looping while `i` is bigger or equal to `indexPath.row`, so if `indexPath.row` is 0 this loop will never end.

Third you do not need so many string, you can format it in one go

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.row; i++) {
    NSString *imageName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", i+1];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

But now you're just overriding the same image to get only the latest image show.
If you want row 1 to have `1.jpg` and row 2 `2.jpg` then a loop isn't needed at all. You can just assign the image directly:

```
NSString *imageName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row+1];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: Also the comparison is always false: **i >= indexPath.row**

Comment: @TamásZahola: No, it's true the first time.

Comment: @TamásZahola, was still writing  about all the mistakes  ;)

Comment: and now with the fixed code, you are adding all the 3 images to the same cell :)

Comment: @KaszásDávid You are right :s the code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have your images like this:

```
0.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
...
```

Then you should do this in *cellForRowAtIndexPath:* delegate method:

```
NSString *imageName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexpath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

No for loop, no appending.